# Filtering Datatables through a multiselect dropdown list in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a single select dropdown function in ajax and successfully fetched the data into datatables. However, I tried to add multiple in my ajax function to get the multiselect function. However, it does not work well. Here is my controller:

```
public function fnFilter(Request $request)
{

    if(request()->ajax())
     {
      if(!empty($request->dataGender))
      {
       $data = DB::table('modified_dpprs')
         ->select('id', 'Fn', 'Ln', 'Umur', 'Phone', 'Dob','St', 'Country','Zip','Ct','Jantina')
         ->where('Jantina', $request->dataGender)
         ->where('Bangsa_updated', $request->ethnicity)
         ->get();
      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('modified_dpprs')
         ->select('id', 'Fn', 'Ln', 'Umur', 'Phone', 'Dob','St', 'Country','Zip','Ct','Jantina')
         ->get();
      }
      return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
     }

    $dataName = DB::table('modified_dpprs')
                    ->select('Age')
                    ->groupBy('Age')
                    ->orderBy('Age', 'ASC')
                    ->get();

    return view('pages.custom', compact('dataName'));   
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      fill_datatable();

      function fill_datatable(dataAge = '')
      {
          var dataTable = $('#table_data').DataTable({
              processing: true,
              serverSide: true,
              ajax:{
                data:{dataAge:dataAge}
              },
              columns: [
                  {
                      data:'id',
                      name:'id'
                  },
                  {
                      data:'Fn',
                      name:'Fn'
                  },
                  {
                      data:'Ln',
                      name:'Ln'
                  }

              ]


          });
      }
```

Blade:

```
<select id="dataAge" class="form-control select2-allow-clear"  style="width:200px;" name="Age" >
                                                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                                                                @foreach ( $dataName as $item)
                                                                                <option value="{{$item->Age}}">{{$item->Age}}</option>
                                                                                @endforeach
                                                                        </select>
```

What should I do to fetch the data from multiselect dropdown to datatable?

Comment: Check your ajax, i thinks it's wrong, also where is the ajax to fetch dropdown data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
         url:"getDataAge",
         type: "POST",
         data:{_token:csrf_token},
         success:function (result) {
         var options_grp = "";
         options_grp = "<option></option>";
         for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
             options_grp = options_grp + "<option  value='" +result[i].name+"_"+result[i].id+"'>"+result[i].name+"</option>"
         }
         $(options_grp).appendTo('#dataAge');
       }
     });
     $('#dataAge').select2({placeholder: "Select Legal Category *"})
```

Try this code, and fetch the in backend side and change the id's name accordingly, also change the url above as per your API endpoint name.